# Chrome Extention: Unchecked runtime.lastError: Failed to parse or set cookie named "ASP.NET_SessionId"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, samesite

I have developed a Chrome extention that modifies web pages for an ASP.net system used at my workplace.

Due to the new Cookie restrictions introduced in recent versions of Chrome, I have to remove the SameSite  lax cookie and replace it with a SameSite none, secure cookie.

The organisation has recently updated Chrome from 75 to 80. Now it works for some people and is broken for others.

When attempting to use `Chrome.cookies` api, the error is `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Failed to parse or set cookie named "ASP.NET_SessionId"`.

Everybody appears to be running the same version of Chrome, and the cookie key is always the same.

See below for code. I have replaced the urls for this example.

```
function sameSiteCookieMaker() {
    chrome.cookies.get({
        "url": "https://example.example.example.com.au",
        "name": "ASP.NET_SessionId"
    }, function(cookie) {
        state = cookie.value
        chrome.cookies.remove({
            "url": "https://example.example.example.com.au",
            "name": "ASP.NET_SessionId"
        }, function(cookie2) {
            chrome.cookies.set({
                "url": "https://example.example.example.com.au",
                "domain": "example.example.example.com.au",
                "httpOnly": true,
                "name": "ASP.NET_SessionId",
                "path": "/",
                "sameSite": "no_restriction",
                "secure": true,
                "storeId": "0",
                "value": state
            })
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: The problem may be inside those hidden parts as Chrome recently started to reject URLs with a leading dot like `https://.mydomain.com`, see https://crbug.com/1003394. The solution is to remove the dot and use `domain` field.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have the leading dot in the URLs. I have updated the example code to show the structure of the URLs. Also, as mentioned, the same code is working for some but not others (all using the same version of Chrome)

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome then. Try examining the exact values used on those machines e.g. maybe add console.log for `state`, `url`, etc.

Comment: I agree. I should have mentioned earlier that when I run my unpacked version on those machines, it works!?

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error. I solved it by following those rules:

1. **url** should contain the value of **domain**. You are not allowed to use a different domain name for **url**.
2. Chrome rejects any **url** with a leading dot, like `https://.example.com/`.
3. **url** should match with **secure**. That means, whenever **secure** is true, **url** should start with **http*s***.

Comment: In my case the error was because I tried to set **secure: false** cookie on **https** url

Comment: @traxium yeah, that's my case too

Answer (score 0):

i got the same error, and after a little research i found out my cookie size exceeded the size limit.

Comment: you can decrease the value of your cookie by dividing the data between multiple cookies.

Comment: or just dont use cookies